# How to add a button to a sidebar widget?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, action-hook

I am quite new to WordPress and I want to add a custom button to the admin dashboard in the [PointFinder](https://themeforest.net/item/point-finder-directory-wordpress-theme/10298703) theme. I am aware of the action hook concept and already successfully implemented my own action hook with `do_action_ref_array()` and called it from the `functions.php` with `add_action()`.

**Approach 1 (put button definition statically into php-file)**

The target sidebar widget at which I want to add an additional button is built in the 'dashboard-page.php' file. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
$pfmenu_output .= ($setup11_reviewsystem_check == 1) ? '<li><a href="'.$setup4_membersettings_dashboard_link.$pfmenu_perout.'ua=reviews"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-377"></i> '. $setup29_dashboard_contents_rev_page_menuname.'</a></li>' : '';
$pfmenu_output .= '<li><a href="http://my.testsite.com/market"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i> '. esc_html__('Car Market','pointfindert2d').'</a></li>';
$pfmenu_output .= '<li><a href="'.esc_url(wp_logout_url( home_url() )).'"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i> '. esc_html__('Logout','pointfindert2d').'</a></li>';
```

The second line is my static approach. The button is added to the sidebar widget correctly. But I need to put this code to the `functions.php` of my `Child-Theme` in order to keep it during future update procedures.

**Approach 2 (more dynamic with a self defined action-hook)**

I also tried to add my own action hook instead of statically adding the button (replaced the second line with an action hook definition:

```
$pfmenu_output .= ($setup11_reviewsystem_check == 1) ? '<li><a href="'.$setup4_membersettings_dashboard_link.$pfmenu_perout.'ua=reviews"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-377"></i> '. $setup29_dashboard_contents_rev_page_menuname.'</a></li>' : '';
do_action_ref_array( 'pf_add_widget_button', array(&$pfmenu_output) );
$pfmenu_output .= '<li><a href="'.esc_url(wp_logout_url( home_url() )).'"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i> '. esc_html__('Logout','pointfindert2d').'</a></li>';
```

Afterwards I added an `add_action()` call to my child-theme's `function.php` and added the button there, which works also fine:

```
function swi_add_button_to_widget(&$pfmenu_output) {
    $pfmenu_output .= '<li><a href="http://my.testsite.com/market"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i> '. esc_html__('Car Market,'pointfindert2d').'</a></li>';
}
add_action( 'pf_add_widget_button', 'swi_add_button_to_widget' );
```

**Problem Definition**

But both approaches described above will only work until I update the PointFinder theme for the first time, since `dashboard-page.php` will most probably be overriden during the update.

I did not find any pre-made action-hooks implemented by the theme development team by searching through all the files looking for `do_action()` and `do_action_ref_array()`. Nothing...

**Solution ?**

Therefore, is there any other way to get access to this `$pfmenu_output` variable from within my child-theme in order to add an extra button?

Am I completely stuck when the theme developers **did not** build-in some pre-made action-hooks for this specific purpose?

Comment: Why don't you just edit dashboard-page.php file from your child theme?

Comment: I don't bother looking through files, in the front and backend if you install Simply Show Hooks you can see all hooks and filters on your site and in your admin. Then you can find one nearby if you can't find a specific one and use priorities to stick it above or below another area.

Comment: Why are you adding the button in the theme or child theme. Make a plugin

Comment: Thanks for the numerous feedbacks. I will try to understand all of your ideas. It will take some time, but I will respond to all of you.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek: If I copy the `dashboard-page.php`  and its folder structure to my child-theme, it will not be updated if the publisher goes and changes/updates anything within that file, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1: Copy `dashboard-page.php` to your child theme

I'm just expanding on [Sebastian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348856/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-sidebar-widget#comment72015465_42348856). You could copy the whole `dashboard-page.php`  file (with your self-added action hook) to your child theme folder. Then, you will have to search for the place in the parent theme where the `dashboard-page.php` file is included. Hopefully it is included by one of the parent theme's [standard template files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List). Then you simply copy that template file to your child theme to override it. Then you would have to change that line that includes the `dashboard-page.php` file to include the same file in the child folder instead.

For example, if the `page.php` template file has something like this:

```
include (get_template_directory() . '/dashboard-page.php')
```

You can copy the `page.php` file to your child theme and change that line to this:

```
include (get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dashboard-page.php')
```

Note that [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) retrieves the path to the child theme folder and [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) retrieves  the path to the parent theme folder.

**Important:** It's possible that the the `dashboard-page.php` file is not included by one of the standard template files that can be overridden, but instead included by other non-standard template files that are included by the parent theme. In that case, you will have to copy every included file down to the `dashboard-page.php` file. And make sure each `include` is using the child theme version of each file.

### Option 2: Use Javascript/jQuery

One alternative approach would be to use javascript code to insert the button. You could add javascript code to one of your child theme templates to dynamically change the menu after the page loads. I took a look at a demo of the theme and it looks like the list element for the sidebar has a class named "pf-sidebar-menu". You could just add the following code that targets that class and inserts your button after the first list item:

```js
jQuery(".pf-sidebar-menu > li:nth-child(1)").after('<li><a href="http://my.testsite.com/market"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i>Car Market</a></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pf-sidebar-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-377"></i>Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

FYI, an easy way to add the above code to your site would be to add the following to your **child theme's** functions.php file. This creates a script tag at the footer of your site with the above code. You might have to add additional checks to target a specific page or pages.

```
<?php
function js_add_sidebar_button() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".pf-sidebar-menu > li:nth-child(1)").after('<li><a href="http://my.testsite.com/market"><i class="pfadmicon-glyph-476"></i>Car Market</a></li>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'js_add_sidebar_button' );
```

Comment: option 2 is less cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! I will try to implement your proposals and report back asap. One question in advance: Your option 1 will not account for the case that the `dashboard-page.php` might be updated by the publisher - correct?

Comment: @salocinx Yes that is correct. It is possible that new features are added in `dashboard-page.php` that won't be available on your site since you are using an old copy of that file. In that case, Allen is probably correct here, option 2 is less cumbersome and less "destructive" in case of future updates.

Comment: @salocinx I probably used the wrong word when I said destructive. I meant that it is more compatible with future updates. I don't believe the first method will actually break anything.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: You're a genius and you really read my mind :-) I was just about thinking how to integrate the jQuery call. I know lots from assembler up to Java, but web development is still kind of mistery to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

use `PHP Code Widget` plugin

[PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/)